# Update multiple rows with Propel 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I need to execute following query (Using Propel 1.4/Symfony 1.4)

```
update notification
set read=1
where to=6 AND
    action=0
```

For this, I wrote following code in symfony 1.4

```
$c=new Criteria()
$c->add(NotificationPeer::TO, $memberId, Criteria::EQUAL);
$c->add(NotificationPeer::ACTION, 0, Criteria::EQUAL);
$notification = NotificationPeer::doSelect($c);

foreach($notification as $notice)
{
    $notice->setRead(1);
    $notice->save();
}
```

Its working but if there are 100's of notification for any user, it will cost 100s of query and unnecessary load to server. I looked on doUpdate method of propel, I guess it can work for me but unable to figure out how.

IS there any way (I know there is but I don't know it) to do all that stuff in single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should build two criteria:

- one for the where clause
- the other one for the update clause.

```php
// Build WHERE criteria
$wherec = new Criteria();
$wherec->add(NotificationPeer::TO, $memberId, Criteria::EQUAL);
$wherec->add(NotificationPeer::ACTION, 0, Criteria::EQUAL);

// Build updated field criteria
$updc = new Criteria();
$updc->add(NotificationPeer::READ, 1);

BasePeer::doUpdate($wherec, $updc, $con);
```

It performs one (could be big) query. See [this snippet](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/50).